# Object sender Attribute Value

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem i want retrieve value of data-bound field reg_id in back-end on the event of radio button selection change. Please tell me i am doing wrong.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="reg_id" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">                       

<Columns>
<asp:BoundField  DataField="reg_id" Visible="false" />

<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>

<div style="width:100px; float:left;">
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('username') %>" ></asp:Label>
</div>

<div style="width:100px; float:left;">
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('country') %>" ></asp:Label>
</div>

<div style="width:100px; float:left;">
<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('city') %>" ></asp:Label>
</div>

<div style="width:100px; float:left;">
<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('locality') %>" ></asp:Label>
</div>

<div style="width:100px; float:left;">
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="No of Posts"></asp:Label>
</div>

<asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="change_attributes" value='<%#Eval("reg_id")%>'  />

<asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />


</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Back-end code: Here i want retrieve value of data-bound field reg_id value by object sender Value Attributes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{

RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("RadioButton1");

RadioButton radio2 = (RadioButton)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("RadioButton2");

string id = "";

RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)sender;

id = btn.Attributes.ToString();              

}
```

Comment: you need to get values for all rows ? why for loop? you dont need the value which has been bound to radio causing postback ?

Comment: actually i want retrieve value of reg_id where radio button is checked. not all. on the event of radio button checked change

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
protected void change_attributes(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = (sender as RadioButton).Attributes["value"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Amir Abbas Sherafatian